# Image not being displayed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck in an easy but so difficult task.
I am having a string that contains a single '@' sign.
The first part of string is a path of type :  GroupPictures/G261-MyGroup/GU53-user2.png
Second part is a name Like say USER.

Now i need to seperate these two parts using javascript and display them as html so i did something like this :

```
var parts=this.toString().split("@");
            var myusername=parts[1];
            var filenamee=parts[0].trim();
            alert(filenamee);
            if ($.cometChat.loginUserName == this) { //login user
                sb[sb.length] = "<span class='one_test'><img style='border-radius:100%;float:left;width:35px;' src="+filenamee+" /><div class='chat_account_name'>" + myusername + "</div><div class='status_offline'></div></span><br>";
            }
```

But the problem is image is not being displayed though the name is displayed right.I want to know am i missing some quotes to close or what is problem with it ?

Problem is with this line only :

```
"<span class='one_test'><img style='border-radius:100%;float:left;width:35px;' src="+filenamee+" /><div class='chat_account_name'>" + myusername + "</div><div class='status_offline'></div></span><br>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
              src='"+filenamee+"'
```

not

```
           src="+filenamee+"
```

so it will be like

```
         src='asdasd'
```

not

```
       src=asdasd
```

Comment: HTML5 makes it acceptable to not using quotation marks when setting attributes, so I'm not sure if that weighs in here or not, but I had the same guess as you.

Comment: sb[sb.length] = "<span class='one_test'><img style='border-radius:100%;float:left;width:35px;' src='"+filenamee+"' /><div class='chat_account_name'>" + myusername + "</div><div class='status_offline'></div></span><br>"; ALSO NOT SERVE THE PURPOSE

Comment: But not everyone has html5 :(

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Its still not been visible

Comment: @user3522121 maybe 100% border radius is not acceptable?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik No if i give the path then it displays the image.But when i store that in a variable like this then its not showing